# Powershell script value fetching

Tags: powershell

I wanted to fetch default gatway using powershell script and I am able to get it as below.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable |
    where { $_.destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.mask -eq '0.0.0.0'} | 
        Sort-Object metric1 | select nexthop | select-object -first 1
```

**The result**

```
nexthop
-------
0.0.0.0
```

However I want to fetch only the value "0.0.0.0", not the header, any solution for this ?

Comment: You should get property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get property value using either of following scripts.

*Using `(your script).PropertyName`:*

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable |
    where { $_.destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.mask -eq '0.0.0.0'} | 
        Sort-Object metric1 | select nexthop | select-object -first 1).nexthop
```

Or by using *Using `your script | select -ExpandProperty PropertyName`:*

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable |
    where { $_.destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.mask -eq '0.0.0.0'} | 
        Sort-Object metric1 | select nexthop | select-object -first |
            select -ExpandProperty nexthop
```

Comment: **Note:** The answer is general and shows how you can get value of a property. In general, as also mentioned by [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47863981/3110834), it's better to not use select-object multiple times when you can achieve the same result using a single select-object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Select-Object cmdlet multiple time.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable -Filter "Destination = '0.0.0.0' AND Mask = '0.0.0.0'" |    
        Sort-Object metric1 | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty nexthop
```

or

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable -Filter "Destination = '0.0.0.0' AND Mask = '0.0.0.0'" |    
        Sort-Object metric1 | Select-Object -First 1).nexthop
```